# FBX import error (Assertion Error, importing from 3ds Max)

Tags: import, error

[image: **Error I'm getting while importing FBX model from 3ds Max into Blender**]

FBX import stopped working for an unknown reason, reinstalled blender and made default system setup. Still, nothing changed.

Comment: what version of blender?

Comment: Is it just one fbx or any / all. If one,  can you post a link to the fbx.   @Galactic_Cat version 2.82 see the path of the error message.